# PostgreSQL Streaming Replication Tools - Windows

Tags: postgresql, replication, clustering, failover

Is there any clusterware available for PostgreSQL clusters running on Windows OS? I'm specifically interested in automatic failover and STONITH functionality. I've done a fairly extensive Google search and had no luck so far.

Thanks.

Comment: Repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/31571126/398670

Comment: Short version: For windows, AFAIK, options are limited. Most customers of the company I work for who use Windows still have Linux-based PostgreSQL servers. The relatively few who use Windows servers do so as part of larger existing cluster systems.